# Alternative to Robot class (selenium script with linux)

Tags: linux, selenium, automation

Is there any alternative to the Robot class that works in Linux to imitate the mouse movements like copy/paste?

The following code works in windows but not in Linux OS. Can anyone please suggest if there is any alternate way to do the same in linux. Thank you.

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(fileName);
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.delay(250);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.delay(90);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Actions class:

https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/keyboard-events-in-selenium/
https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/actions-class-in-selenium/

You can also try Keys.chord():

https://stqatools.com/selenium-keyboard-events/
http://selenium-venkat.blogspot.com/2016/02/17-simulate-pressing-of-multiple-keys.html
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/key-press-in-ctrlplusa-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am trying to automate the following scenario. "When the user clicks the button it pops up a file upload window and the user has to select the file to be uploaded.". Usually sendKeys() work for this scenario. For some reason since the upload pop up triggered after a button click sendKeys() is not working. So even when i use Action class sendKeys i could not meet the need.